# How to add loader in ajax load with async: false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem in load data using ajax, I use async false because I want my ajax process to run first. if it doesn't use async false the display and data will be stacked. how to show my loader in ajax async false?

Iwant to add my loader. this is my loader

```
$("#loading").show();
```

This is my select event when change

```
$('#boothFill').on('change', function () {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tbltransaction')) {
        $('#tbltransaction').DataTable().destroy();
    }
    $('#areaFill').find('.optArea').remove();
    $('#acamFill').find('.optAcam').remove();
    if ($("#boothFill").val() != "all") {
        $('#statisticData').find('.removeCardStat').remove();
        ajaxCardStatistic($('#dateStartTanggal').val(), $('#dateEndTanggal').val(), $('#areaFill').val(), $('#boothFill').val(), $('#acamFill').val(), $("#productFill").val());
    }else{
        $('#statisticData').find('.removeCardStat').remove();
    }
    ajaxArea($('#boothFill').val(), $('#acamFill').val());
    ajaxAcam($('#areaFill').val(), $('#boothFill').val());
    ajaxGet($('#dateStartTanggal').val(), $('#dateEndTanggal').val(), $('#areaFill').val(), $('#boothFill').val(), $('#acamFill').val(), $("#productFill").val(), $("#productTypeFill").val());      getAllData($('#dateStartTanggal').val(), $('#dateEndTanggal').val(), $('#areaFill').val(), $('#boothFill').val(), $('#acamFill').val());
});
```

this is a function called when select change

```
function ajaxCardStatistic(dateStartTanggal, dateEndTanggal, area, booth, acam, product){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dashboard/statisticCard",
        data: {
            dateStart : dateStartTanggal,
            dateEnd : dateEndTanggal,
            area : area,
            booth : booth,
            acam : acam,
            product : product,
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response.data, function(item, data){
                if (!$.trim(data.product_type_name)) {
                    var html = "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 removeCardStat'><div class='card'><div class='card-header'><h4>" + data.motoquick_name + " (" + data.jenis + ")</h4></div>";
                }else{
                    var html = "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 removeCardStat'><div class='card'><div class='card-header'><h4>" + data.motoquick_name + " (" + data.jenis + " > " + data.product_type_name + ")</h4></div>";
                }
                html += "<div class='card-body' style='padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;'><div class='row text-center'>";
                html += "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'><h4>" + data.transaction + "</h4><span>Trx</span></div>";
                html += "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'><h4>" + (data.rate*100).toFixed(0) + "% </h4><span>Avg/Day</span></div>";
                html += "</div></div>";
                html += "<div class='card-footer text-center'>" + rupiah(data.revenue) + " <br><span>Revenue</span></div>";
                html += "</div></div>";
                $("#statisticData").append(html);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you're asking why your loader doesn't show when the ajax call is running, it's because you've used `async: false` and so the browser's UI is blocked waiting for the ajax call to complete. This is why you don't use `async: false`, because it locks up the UI of the browser. I don't know what you mean by "...if it doesn't use async false the display and data will be stacked..." but whatever that problem is, you can (and should) fix it without `async: false`.

Comment: [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) may be useful understanding how to correctly handle an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use 

beforeSend: function() {

                        $("#loading").show();
                        }


Example
function ajaxCardStatistic(dateStartTanggal, dateEndTanggal, area, booth, acam, product){   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "dashboard/statisticCard",
                data: {
                    dateStart : dateStartTanggal,
                    dateEnd : dateEndTanggal,
                    area : area, 
                    booth : booth, 
                    acam : acam, 
                    product : product, 
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                beforeSend: function() {

                        $("#loading").show();
                        },
                success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response.data, function(item, data){
                        if (!$.trim(data.product_type_name)) {
                            var html = "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 removeCardStat'><div class='card'><div class='card-header'><h4>" + data.motoquick_name + " (" + data.jenis + ")</h4></div>";
                        }else{
                            var html = "<div class='col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 removeCardStat'><div class='card'><div class='card-header'><h4>" + data.motoquick_name + " (" + data.jenis + " > " + data.product_type_name + ")</h4></div>";
                        }
                        html += "<div class='card-body' style='padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;'><div class='row text-center'>";
                        html += "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'><h4>" + data.transaction + "</h4><span>Trx</span></div>";
                        html += "<div class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12'><h4>" + (data.rate*100).toFixed(0) + "% </h4><span>Avg/Day</span></div>";
                        html += "</div></div>";
                        html += "<div class='card-footer text-center'>" + rupiah(data.revenue) + " <br><span>Revenue</span></div>";
                        html += "</div></div>";
                        $("#statisticData").append(html);
                    });
                 $("#loading").hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put ajax before in loader like this 
In your code **dataType: "JSON",** after

```
beforeSend: function() {
   $("#loader").show();
},
```

After success in hide this loader like this

```
$("#loader").hide();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work.Do show first and wrap your async:false ajax into a setTimeout.

```
$("#loading").show();
setTimeout(function(){
 $.ajax({....async: false,});
},500);
```